# Android navigation bar that doesn't reload between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I want to implement a navigation bar on android that will look like the iPhone navigation bar. I have done a lot of reading and the immediate answer is the ActionBar.

But from what I understand, if I switch activities, **then the ActionBar keep reloading itself on each Activity's `onCreate()` method. That's not good behavior for my app**: I need something similar to the TabBar, but without tabs, as I only need a home page button, settings button and the app's name.

So my question is: is there a navigation bar in android that can stay always on the screen between Activities and reloads itself (I think that Fragments are out of the question also, because they live in a certain Activity)?

**EDIT:** I can simplify the question: is there a way to place a custom view in the screen and keeping it between Activities changes, without reloading it on each Activity's onCreate() method?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve what you want with the action bar. Read the [tabs section of the action bar doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs), and you'll see that the activity body is loaded using fragments, hence the whole action bar is not reloaded.

As a side note, it's generaly a bad practice to mimic iphone's component. [Android has specific design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html), and you should stick to it unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: thanks for your reply. what if I want to support SDK prior to 3.0? is there an easier solution instead of using some external library or the compatibility package?

Comment: There is a sdk sample called 'ActionBarSample', or you may check [action bar sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Comment: as far as I can see (also in the ActionBarSample or  action bar sherlock) - the only solution is to use Fragments. isn't there a way to use different Activities and not load the ActionBar every time?